# Is tensorflow tf.compat.v1 can be used with RTX 4090?

Tags: tensorflow

Base on to tensorflow website tensorflow_gpu-1.15.0 is compatible with CUDA 10.0
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu
I am using tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior() to ensure my code that written in tensorflow 1.x working in TF 2.x framework. According to nvidia the RTX 4090 is not supported by tensorflow 1.x because it is running in higher CUDA version so my question is if I am using tf.compat.v1 will my application run with RTX 4090?

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem, I used RTX3050 and also needed to use Tensorflow 1.15, which requires CUDA 10, but Nvidia says that you need CUDA 11.2 or higher.

In order to run Tensorflow 1.15 on newer graphic cards, try [NVIDIA-Modified Tensorflow](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorflow) which is based on Tensorflow 1.15.

For CUDA and cuDNN versions I have tried working, it is 11.8 and 8.1.0 respectively.